# How to implement observer pattern the way django signals implements it

Tags: python, django, fastapi, observer-pattern, django-signals

there's a design issue i have with a problem i'm currently working that will require a certain observable to emit values whenever it reaches a computation milestone,so i need values emitted intermediately,i discovered django implements something similar with signals which is just an implementation of the observer pattern but i really wanted to implement it the way django signals is implemented because observers subscribing to an observable( e.g after saving a model to the db i.e post_save signal) is very much decoupled in the sense that the observing function only needs to be annotated with the `@receiver` decorator.

So i took a look at django's source code and tried creating a simple version of the signal mechanism i created a signals class in one module with the decorator :

```
class Signal:
    def __init__(self):
        self.observers=[]
    def connect(self,receiver):
        self.observers.append(receiver.__name__)
    def send(self,sender,**named):
        return [
            (receiver,mem_dec(signal=self,sender=sender,**named))
            for receiver in self.observers
            ]
        
        
class Child(Signal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


def mem_dec(signal,**kwargs):
    def wrapper(func):
        signal.connect(func, **kwargs)
        return func
    return wrapper

if __name__ == "__main__":
    send_signal=Child()
    send_signal.send(sender="class_child",a="henry")
```

and i placed the decorated function in another module to serve as the observer:

```
from .signals import mem_dec
from .signals import Child

@mem_dec(Child,sender=Child)
def hello(a,**kwargs):
    print(f'hey {a}')
```

i noticed in my implementation doesn't work which i expected but the issue is that's what i could reproduce from the source code,i'm very confused about how they implemented their `send()` and `connect()`  mechanism,all i want to achieve with this is for the signal subclass call all decorated functions, i made the Child class the signal and sender at the same time cause i'm just trying to reproduce the simplest example.